# UIViewController Transition from right to left

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am opening second view controller on button click from fist viewController,but its animating from bottom.I want to open it in right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be presenting the second view controller on first view button tap.

The view transition from right to left will work when you do pushing a second view.
For enable pushing the second view, at first your first view should be inside navigation controller. 
     If your first view is already inside a navigation controller then do the following for pushing second view:
Case 1: If your are using storyboard and First view is already embedded in Navigation controller

1. set `storyboardID` for the second view controller in storyboard (Eg. here `storyboardID` is same as the class name)
2. Do this code on your button tap of first view:

   ```
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animates:YES];
   ```

Case 2: If you are using storyboard but First view controller is not embedded in Navigation Controller:
1. Embed the First view in Navigarion controller

1.1. Open storyboard file and select the First View Controller

1.2. Goto Editor->Embed In-> Navigation Controller.

2. Then do the step Case:1's 2nd step.

Case 3: If you are using XIB files and first view is not in navigation controller.
 1. For loading first view in AppDelegate.m application:didFnishLoading: method do as follows:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

2. Then for pushing second view on first view button do as follows:

   ```
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animates:YES];
   ```

If this is not helpful, then just post what you did exactly then exact solution can be given. Because what approach you are using to load view is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: i have done like dis :- ViewProfileController *objViewProfileController = [ViewProfileController alloc];
    [self presentViewController:objViewProfileController animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[self pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
[self presentViewController:yourViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The first piece of code pushes the second view controller in the screen from right to left.

The second line of code, which is what you have probably written in your app presents the view controller modally, meaning from bottom to top.

Comment: both are view controller not a navigation controller.I am not using storyboard

Comment: Okay. Basically the problem is that you are using presentViewController instead of pushViewController method. Check out my edited answer.

Comment: thank you for your reply but for that we have to add navigation controller